# Django Dynamic Choices for a Field Based On Another Field

Tags: django, django-models

I have a simple model, let's call it `Person`.

`Person` has a `CharField` named `Topic` with some `choices`, for example:
'Food', 'Cars', 'Colors'.

`Person` has another `CharField` named `Favorite`, which currently has no choices.

I would like to populate `Favorite`'s choices according to the selected value in `Topic`.

Let's say I'm in the admin UI editing a `Person` and I set his `Topic` to be 'Food', so I want the values in the drop down list of `Favorite` to change to: 'Pizza', 'Cake', 'French Fries'.

How can I do this with Django?

To me the solution sounds like JavaScript but I'd rather put it as my last option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want the field Favorite to dynamically change based on what was selected in Topic, you'll have to create a Javascript function for that. Unless you do a two-step page, which would be not so user friendly.

Comment: @Ev. Are you 100% sure about that?

Comment: Yes. If you want it to change dynamically (no page refresh), yes.